# Using conditional tags in AIML

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml

I am trying to have a conditional tag functionality within my AIML file.
I am using a python script, with PyAIML and pb_py libraries.

In my current implementation I have it set so that I can set the predicate value in my python script dynamically for the conditional tag to be either 'speech' or 'text':

```
<!-- 5 Legacy -->
<category><pattern>ARE YOU NAMED AFTER *</pattern><template><srai>legacyresponse</srai></template></category>
<category><pattern>WHO ARE YOU NAMED AFTER</pattern><template><srai>legacyresponse</srai></template></category>
<category><pattern>LEGACYRESPONSE</pattern>
<template>
<condition name = "inputtype">
    <li value = "speech">Some response</li>
    <li value = "text">Some text response.</li>
</condition>
<srai>promptuser</srai>
</template>
</category>
```

In my AIML file I have multiple responses functionality implemented as follows:

```
<category><pattern>_ YOUR DAD *</pattern><template><srai>parentsresponse</srai></template></category>
<category><pattern>PARENTS</pattern><template><srai>parentsresponse</srai></template></category>
<category><pattern>PARENTS</pattern><template><srai>parentsresponse</srai></template></category>
<category><pattern>PARENTSRESPONSE</pattern>
<template>
<random>
<li>Response 1</li>
<li>Response 2</li>
<li>Response 3</li>
</random>
<srai>promptuser</srai>
</template>
</category>
```

I would like to have both the multiple responses and conditional functionality, for example if I pass in the 'speech' condition, it picks either the

tag with the value set as 'speech' or the

tag where value is not specified:

```
<category><pattern>LEGACYRESPONSE</pattern>
<template>
<condition name = "inputtype">
    <li value = "speech">Some Speech only response</li>
    <li>Some speech or text response</li>
    <li value = "text">Some text only response.</li>
</condition>
<srai>promptuser</srai>
</template>
</category>
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not able to understand your question. You have set the "inputtype" as "Speech" using Python and now you want 2 responses from AIML? or you want either of Speech response or when there is no value?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your full requirement. But as per my understanding, you are facing issue with condition tag.

whenever user selected "speech" or "text" please set "inputtype" to the corresponding value. If a user didn't select any of these then the value of "inputtype" is "unknown".

```
<condition name="inputtype">
    <li value="speech">Your stuff </li>
    <li value="text">Your stuff </li>
    <li value="unknown">Your stuff </li>
</condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to the below sample AIML code and make changes accordingly in your file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml version="1.0">
<category>
    <pattern>WHAT ABOUT MOVIES</pattern>
    <template>
    I love talking about movies too!
    <think><set name="topic">MOVIE</set></think>
    <br/>Did you like comedy movies?
    </template>
</category>
<topic name="MOVIE">
    <category>
        <pattern>YES</pattern>
        <that>* LIKE COMEDY  *</that>
        <template>You seems an interesting person!</template>
    </category>
    <category>
        <pattern>NO</pattern>
        <that>* LIKE COMEDY  *</that>
        <template>You seems a boring person!</template>
    </category>
</topic>
</aiml>
```